# I need to extract three columns from a file

Tags: dataset, text-files, extract

I am doing a project in Association Rule Mining. For my data set, I need to extract three columns from a text file.

Here is the link for the text [file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/59650664/project.txt).

I need to extract Billno, Product and Batch columns and write them on to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use grep
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/290545-using-a-grep-command-in-a-c-program-in-linux/

Otherwise, that data is consistent, all the bill numbers are the same length and and appear to be easily Regex'ed
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/